# Getting an audio notification when webcam is turned on

Tags: windows-10, webcam

I have a Windows 10 Home laptop and, for privacy reasons, I would want to hear when my webcam is activated. I know that there is a led light which is turned on when the webcam activates + I have enabled the OSD message, but I would want an audible notification instead (as both the led and the OSD are silent).

Is there any way of achieving this? I would be open to even scripting something in VBScript, but I don't know how to get hooked into the webcam activation event.

Comment: You could try asking on https://www.reddit.com/r/Blind/

Comment: just an alternative solution: if you don't find any solution, you can apply tap on your camera or you can disable your camera drivers for privacy purposes.

Comment: What does exactly means "camera is activated" The camera device is ready and wating for client? Some program is connected to camera and receiving the stream?

Comment: Some program is connected and receiving the stream. At least on my system, once I start using the camera (e.g. in Zoom), a LED is turned on and only turned off once I stop. As previously stated, I enabled OSD notifications, so I also get an on-screen message telling me that "Camera On"e.g.  once I start a Zoom video call.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two years later, and I found a solution myself. I noticed that Windows 10 tracks the camera status via the Privacy --> App Permissions menu:

[image: Windows settings screenshot]

After some googling, I found that this data is stored in the registry:
[image: Registry screenshot]

Each key prefix represents an app ("desktop apps", i.e. non-Microsoft store apps, are below the "NonPackaged" key prefix). Each app having 3 subkeys:

- Value: if camera usage is allowed at all,
- LastUsedTimeStart: the last time the camera access was started by the app,
- LastUsedTimeStop: the last time the camera access was stopped for the app.

So if we want to get an notification each time anything related to the camera happens for any app (i.e. privilege is granted/revoked, access starts/stops), then we can use the Windows Management Interface to pick up the registry changes for the whole subtree:

```powershell
#Requires -version 2.0

$voice = New-Object -ComObject Sapi.spvoice
$voice.rate = 0
$voice.volume = 100

$user = [System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity]::GetCurrent().User.Value
Register-WmiEvent -Query "SELECT * FROM RegistryTreeChangeEvent WHERE Hive = 'HKEY_USERS' AND RootPath = '$user\\Software\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\CapabilityAccessManager\\ConsentStore\\webcam'"  -SourceIdentifier WebKeyChanged
while($true) {
    Wait-Event -SourceIdentifier WebKeyChanged
    Remove-Event -SourceIdentifier WebKeyChanged
    
    $voice.speak("Webcam!")
}
```

Unfortunately, this also triggers when the camera stops, so it might be a little noisy. Based on https://stackoverflow.com/a/145934/7612556, we can't really narrow it down easily - so if anyone wants to use this approach, you might need to either debounce the audio or add a more sophisticated registry tracking (e.g. exporting the subtree in memory on each event + comparing what changed to see if it's worth triggering an audio notification).

The upside is that this also works for new apps (i.e. completely new keys in the registry).

In my case, I was interested mainly in a specific app and just in the "start access" event. For that narrow use case, the following WQL query narrows it down:

```sql
SELECT * FROM RegistryValueChangeEvent WHERE Hive = 'HKEY_USERS' AND KeyPath = '$user\\Software\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\CapabilityAccessManager\\ConsentStore\\webcam\\NonPackaged\\C:#Program Files (x86)#SomeProgramName#SomeProgram.exe' AND ValueName='LastUsedTimeStart'
```

Note that for this "targeted" script, the app that you're concerned about must have requested camera access at least once before this script can be run successfully (otherwise the query will fail as the registry key would not exist).

To have the script running all the time, I followed the answers from this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20575257/how-do-i-run-a-powershell-script-when-the-computer-starts

Comment: There is a problem with this.  Only new apps comply with this permission.  Legacy apps do not, but they can still access the camera.  Maybe there is a camera that has this feature.

Comment: The original question wasn't about complying with permissions or not - it was about detecting usage. At least for my use case, I have a really old app (~10 years or so), and its usage appears in the registry and I can detect it using this script. I actually did not find any app that does not appear in the registry if it accesses the camera.

Answer (score 3):

Negative answer: Either not possible or the "solution" would be worse than the problem.

**As regarding the Event Viewer**: I have activated and deactivated my camera,
but there was no resulting event to be seen. So there is no solution this way.

**As regarding writing a script** that periodically checks the camera status and shows
an alert if active: There is here a small technical problem.

PowerShell supports queries on devices using the following commands,
but according to my test they do not indicate whether the webcam is activated or not:

```
Get-CimInstance Win32_PnPEntity | where caption -match 'webcam'
Get-WmiObject Win32_PnPEntity | where {$_.caption -match 'webcam'}
```

The webcam API does support getting the status of the webcam by issuing the
[WM_CAP_GET_STATUS message](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/multimedia/wm-cap-get-status).
The only problem is that this a message is to be issued to the capture window
created via the the API
[capCreateCaptureWindowA function](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/vfw/nf-vfw-capcreatecapturewindowa).
However, *the very act of creating this window will turn on the camera*.

It's possible to write a small script that checks periodically the webcam status
([example webcam code](https://www.experts-exchange.com/questions/29056194/VB-Net-2013-Webcam-taking-low-quality-photos-How-do-you-take-full-quality-pictures.html)).
However, every time such a script will run, the LED will light up and
the OSD message will appear.
If this script is for example run every second, just imagine what will happen.

My conclusion is that, even if what you ask for is possible,
the solution will be worse than the problem.

Comment: That's true. Good answer there buddy.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I thought as much... So I think that in the end, the only way to actually do this is at hardware level :)

Comment: Yes, at the camera firmware level, or at the webcam driver level, or even in the application that is capturing the video. If none of them offers such a feature, then your options to do it yourself are very limited.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest that you use this website here:

https://devblogs.microsoft.com/scripting/weekend-scripter-use-powershell-to-find-and-disable-webcams/

It explains how to find and disable a webcam using PowerShell scripting. I assume that you are open to doing anything just to get this to work. If you are that captivated in proceeding with this idea I don't think you would mind editing the script a bit to play a sound or tone instead of disabling the camera and also to run in the background. Here is a head-start.

`[console]::beep(50,1000)`

This should play a 50hz tone in powershell for 1 second (or 1000ms)

Also here is a quick link explaining [this command.](https://redmondmag.com/articles/2018/02/07/play-sound-with-powershell.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

I can build on the answers here to create what you want.
The script below adds a condition to trigger an action only when the LastUsedTimeStart or LastUsedTimeStop is updated since the script was started and additionally outputs the Key value belonging to the process that triggered it. Which could also be used as a condition, of course.

You could implement this as a Scheduled Task so it runs automatically in the background, some pointers follow. A PowerShell window will briefly pop-up right after log on, this window could additionally be hidden using VBScript (such as discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76501747/hidden-powershell-sheduled-task)).

- Scheduled Task General, Run only when user is logged on
- Scheduled Task Trigger, 'At log on' & 'On workstation unlock'
- Scheduled Task Action, Start a program: `powershell`, Arguments: `-ep bypass -windowstyle hidden -file <PathTo\CameraStateMonitor.ps1>`

Example output:
`Camera was last started by MSTeams_8wekyb3d8bbwe at 11/09/2023 17:19:10`

```powershell
# CameraStateMonitor.ps1
# Start Transcript if running from script file
If ($MyInvocation.MyCommand.Path) {
    $WorkingDir = (Split-Path $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Path -Parent)
    $LogPath = "$WorkingDir\$((Get-Item $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Path).BaseName).log"
    Start-Transcript $LogPath
}

$ElgatoSwitch = {
    param($State='on')
    $wr = Invoke-WebRequest -Method POST -Headers @{
        "authorization"="Bearer <token>"
        "Content-Type"="application/json"
    } -Uri "http://192.168.1.140:8123/api/services/light/turn_$State" -Body '{"entity_id":"light.elgato_bw20k1a10412"}'
}
$CameraStartedAction = {
    Write-Host "Camera was last started by $($latest.LastUsedStartName) at $($latest.LastUsedTimeStart)"
    #.$ElgatoSwitch -State on
    [console]::beep(1800,350); $voice.Speak("Webcam enabled") | Out-Null
}
$CameraStoppedAction = {
    Write-Host "Camera was last stopped by $($latest.LastUsedStopName) at $($latest.LastUsedTimeStop)"
    #.$ElgatoSwitch -State off
    [console]::beep(400,500); $voice.Speak("Webcam disabled") | Out-Null
}
$WmiEventHandler = {
    If (!$latest) { $latest = [pscustomobject]@{LastUsedStartName=$null;LastUsedTimeStart=Get-Date;LastUsedStopName=$null;LastUsedTimeStop=Get-Date} }
    $props = Get-ChildItem "Registry::HKEY_USERS\$($user.User.Value)\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\CapabilityAccessManager\ConsentStore\webcam"
    $props | ForEach-Object {
        $propUsedTimeStart = [datetime]::FromFileTime($_.GetValue('LastUsedTimeStart'))
        $propUsedTimeStop  = [datetime]::FromFileTime($_.GetValue('LastUsedTimeStop'))
        If ($propUsedTimeStart -gt $latest.LastUsedTimeStart) {
            $latest.LastUsedStartName = $_.Name -Replace '.*\\'
            $latest.LastUsedTimeStart = $propUsedTimeStart
            .$CameraStartedAction
        }
        If ($propUsedTimeStop  -gt $latest.LastUsedTimeStop) {
            $latest.LastUsedStopName = $_.Name -Replace '.*\\'
            $latest.LastUsedTimeStop = $propUsedTimeStop
            .$CameraStoppedAction
        }
    }
}

$voice = New-Object -ComObject Sapi.spvoice; $voice.rate = 0; $voice.volume = 100
$user = [System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity]::GetCurrent()
Write-Host -b black -f yellow "User:" $user.Name "`r`n SID:" $user.User.Value

$WmiEventQuery = @"
SELECT *
FROM RegistryTreeChangeEvent
WHERE Hive = 'HKEY_USERS'
      AND RootPath = '$($user.User.Value)\\Software\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\CapabilityAccessManager\\ConsentStore\\webcam'
"@
Register-WmiEvent -SourceIdentifier RegistryTreeChangeEvent -Query $WmiEventQuery

try {
    # Monitoring loop
    while($true) {
        Wait-Event -SourceIdentifier RegistryTreeChangeEvent | Out-Null
        #Wait-Event -SourceIdentifier RegistryTreeChangeEvent -Timeout 60 | Out-Null # Return after 60 seconds in case of issues with ChangeEvent not triggering
        Write-Host -b black -f yellow "$(Get-Date) Wait-Event returned"
        Remove-Event -SourceIdentifier RegistryTreeChangeEvent -ea 0
        .$WmiEventHandler
    }
} catch {
    Write-Host "Error occurred:`r`n" + $Error[0]
} finally {
    Get-EventSubscriber -SourceIdentifier RegistryTreeChangeEvent | Unregister-Event
    Stop-Transcript
}
```